# How to remove deprecated $listeners in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, migration

In migration from vue 2 to vue 3, i am getting some compilation warnings. Deprecation of `$listeners` in components is one of those warnings. I have checked official documentation to use `$attrs` by removing `$listeners`. I am new in vue 3. So, not able to understand how to handle those warnings related to listeners.

Here is the snippet:

**1st case:**
**Component 1**

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <input ref="input"
               :value="txtField"
               @input="txtField=$event.target.value"
               :type="inputType"
               :class="inputClass"
               :placeholder="placeholder"
               :disabled="disabled"
               :readonly="readonly"
               :onfocus="disabled&&'this.blur();'"
               :tabindex="tabindex"
               v-on="listenersInput" // here is the method where $listeners used
               @keyup.enter="enterHandler"
               @blur="validateOnEvent"/>
     </div>
</template>

//method 

listenersInput() {
            //var vm = this;
            return Object.assign({}, this.$listeners, {
                input: function(event){ /*vm.$emit('input',event.target.value);*/}
            });
        },
```

**2nd case:**
**Component 2**

```
<template>
  <custom-button 
      v-bind="buttonProps"
      v-on="$listeners"
      :class="buttonClass"
      @click="tooggle">
  </custom-button>
</template>
```

How to handle these two cases?

Answer (score 12):

In Vue 3 `$listeners` moved to `$attrs` you can use `v-bind="$attrs"`. [Here is an article from docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html#listeners-removed)

Additional documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#nested-component-inheritance

Comment: Instead of providing just the link, you could also copy the relevant code here for easier reading.

Comment: The link is now broken, which is why actioning @Sriram's comment is important.

Answer (score 9):

In Vue 2, you could bind all event listeners using `v-on="$listeners"`.

In Vue 3, according to the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance), if you want to apply fallthrough attributes to a non-root element, you have to use `v-bind="$attrs"` which also includes the event listeners.

So this Vue 2 code:

```html
<div>
  <my-button v-on="$listeners">click me</my-button>
</div>
```

Looks like this in Vue 3:

```html
<div>
  <my-button v-bind="$attrs">click me</my-button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is somewhat incorrect advice, even though it is the official advice. while $attrs now contains $listeners, it also includes other things, which may be relied upon to be bound to the default wrapping element or somewhere else by the component so this is a breaking change in any component implementing it.

Comment: You are right @Damon, but I could not find a cleaner way. Suggestions welcome

Comment: @Damon in most cases this is sufficient, also the RFC (https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0031-attr-fallthrough.md#summary) mentiones one can influence this behaviour by not defining any props (so only listeners, style and class are forwarded) or use inheritAttrs: false to explicitly control this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a few times in different forums but I haven't seen any clean code examples.  The example below shows how to use v3 $attrs to bubble events to parents and grandparents and etc, as we would have with $listeners in v2:

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Child v-bind="$attrs" @grandchild-clicked="grandchildClicked" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Child,
  },
  methods:{
    grandchildClicked(){
      console.log("Grandchild clicked!");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Grandchild v-bind="$attrs" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Grandchild from './Grandchild.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Grandchild,
  },
}
</script>
```

**Grandchild.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click="$emit('grandchild-clicked')">Click me!</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: As long as I believe, by logic, this is the correct answer, it doesn't work, or, at least, in my case, it doesn't work.
Despite what the doc states, the events are not passed within the $attrs. Inspecting the Vue debug tool (and logging the $attrs), the event is not there.
Annoyingly, the only solution I found was re-emitting the received event from the Child to the Parent component.

Comment: @Ale I don't doubt it it's troublesome in nature.  I had difficulties getting it to work myself. However, I can confirm that $attrs does work for bubbling events from deeply nested components - I use it frequently, as recently as today.

Comment: it wasn't working for me because I was using the @vue/compat migration tool. It's written in the docs that $attrs is not working for it.... I just missed it. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to use $attrs but if you want to extract listeners from $attrs you can use something like

```
<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return Object.keys(this.$attrs)
        ?.filter(
          (attr) =>
            attr?.startsWith('on') && typeof this.$attrs[attr] === 'function'
        )
        ?.reduce((res, key) => ((res[key] = this.$attrs[key]), res), {});
    },
  },
}

</script>
```